# Keep duplicate keys in array

Tags: php

I am getting data from whois and breaking the data up and putting it into an array with keys but some need multiple keys the same name is there anyway i can add number onto the end of the same named keys to make them unique?

here is my code so far

```
 $test1 =$check_domain->find_whois_details("be.co");

$rows = explode("\n", $test1);
$arr = array('info'=>"");
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $posOfFirstColon = strpos($row, ":");
    if($posOfFirstColon === FALSE)
        $arr['info'] .= $row;
    else
        $arr[substr($row, 0, $posOfFirstColon)] = trim(substr($row, $posOfFirstColon+1));
}

$a = array_map('trim', array_keys($arr));
$b = array_map('trim', $arr);
$arr = array_combine($a, $b);


print($arr["Registry Expiry Date"]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a more manageable solution would be to change your storage structure to a multidimensional array rather than a flat array.

```
$arr[substr($row, 0, $posOfFirstColon)][] = trim(substr($row, $posOfFirstColon+1));
```

In this structure, each name would correspond to an array containing one or more values. This way, the key retains its original value, which would become less meaningful if you appended some arbitrary value to it to keep it unique.

This may not work for your specific scenario, but it's generally a better representation for grouping a set of data by a specific property.

Comment: This is the way i want it to work!,  only problem is the last 3 lines are giving me problems now array_map and array combine with error Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. If you do it this way each key corresponds to a set of values (an array) rather than a single value (although the array may only contain a single value sometimes). I was thinking that if you did it this way, those lines wouldn't be necessary, `$arr` would already hold the data as needed.

Comment: aaa i see now how it works, this might be super simple question but how do i display all values from say key name?

Comment: @JohnO, since each key now contains an array of strings instead of a single string, you would need to iterate that key somehow. `foreach ($arr['name'] as $name) { echo $name; }` for example.

Answer (score 0):

> bool array_key_exists ( mixed $key , array $array )

[array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) — Checks if the given key or index exists in the array

```
<?php
$search_array = array('first' => null, 'second' => 4);

// returns true
array_key_exists('first', $search_array);
?>
```

Using this function, you can check if the key is already existing, in that case just concatenate a number after the key you're inserting !